# Coolant leak on Holden Astra

Tags: coolant, leak, astra, holden

I had a new drive belt fitted about one month ago max. Now suddenly my Astra is leaking coolant severely and the new drive belt is also damaged and this is where the coolant is leaking! Is this an issue caused by poor work done by the mechanic? Any help much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You don't state what year/engine of the Astra. Also, by "drive belt" do you mean the serpentine belt, or a timing belt? Not knowing much about your car (you don't give enough information) is not helping get an answer to you.

Comment: The engine type would be important as they differ widely